# Which is the best functional programming library for Deno?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

During the development I was uncomfortable and found it somewhat difficult using the functions that could be used with Ramda for Node projects. I explored internet but couldn't find some module that would make the things somewhat easy for me?. Can someone help me figure out the best functional programming library for Deno?

Comment: any library that uses plain javascript can be used in Deno.

Comment: Yeh, we can use any NodeJS modules in Deno too by using Deno's node compatibility module. But I tried it using recently it gave me many errors and was not able to run Ramda. If you want to use Deno specific module for functional programming, I would recommend Fae https://deno.land/x/fae. It has already 45+ functions and is inspired by Ramda. The work is in progress.

Comment: You can try also [monads](https://deno.land/x/monads), inspired to Rust, that implements [either](https://deno.land/x/monads@v0.3.4/lib/either), [option](https://deno.land/x/monads@v0.3.4/lib/option) and [result](https://deno.land/x/monads@v0.3.4/lib/result)